# "J'ai bien peur" vs. "J'ai peur", what is the difference?

Tags: grammaire, adverbes

The sentence is

> J'ai bien peur de devoir partir maintenant.

I'm wondering why the word 'bien' is in this sentence and why it's not simply

> J'ai peur de devoir partir maintenant.

My French level is very basic so I'm assuming this is something simple I'm just not getting.

Answer (score 3):

The adverb *bien* can have either an emphatic or a softening role depending on the context.

In that particular case, that's the second possibility so *j'ai bien peur* is weaker than *j'ai peur*, meaning you are not really afraid of anything but simply state there is probably no alternative and you just have to leave now.

*Bien* plays a similar role when used with *aimer*:

> *J'aime l'Italie* - I love Italy.
>
> *J'aime bien l'Italie* - I like Italy.

Comment: just wanted to say thanks for contributing so much to this site. a lot of the other high-rep users have drifted away over the years, which is natural; glad you're still carrying the torch for now.

Answer (score 1):

French present of indicative e.g., je parle, tu parle, etc., may be interpreted as 
I am speaking, I do speak, I speak according to the context.

The use of bien here is to give a clearer emphatic tone.

> **J'ai bien peur de devoir partir maintenant.**
>
> I'm afraid that I have to go **indeed**.

As another example:

> Je lui ai bien dit de s'arrêter.
>
> I did tell him to stop/I told him to stop indeed.